# Retrieving a common property from a set of classes of type foowriter

Tags: c#, reflection

I have a set of classes that all extend the same base class, say
`fooboo : foowriter, foobar : foowriter`. These all output files that have a different extension, say `fooboo --> .boo` and `foobar --> .bar` files.

I'm using reflection to get a list of all concrete types that extend `foowriter`, and I need to get a list of all the extensions that these classes can produce, i.e. `{ ".boo", ".bar" }`

At the moment each `foowriter` knows what format it can produce and this is in a readonly field. I'm keen to keep this knowledge encapsulated within each concrete class, as opposed to implementing a `GetOutputExtension<T>() : where T : foowriter` method in some extra class, as this would couple all the `foowriter`s with that extra utility class.

I don't really want to instantiate the concrete classes as that could be a heavy weight operation.

What's a good pattern or method to get a common property from a set of types without instantiating them?

Comment: I'm pretty sure to make it _safe_ (i.e. avoiding potential runtime bugs) I'd have to have an instance (say a collection of foowriterBuilders) that I could examine. Not amazingly keen on doing that because of the structural changes it would require to implement/use them :/

Answer (score 3):

One option would be to create a custom attribute. This way you'll associate the extension with your classes without having to instantiate them.

Usage:

```
[Output(Extension = ".boo")]
public class fooboo : foowriter { ... }

[Output(Extension = ".bar")]
public class foobar : foowriter { ... }
```

The downside is that this wouldn't be enforced at compile-time.

**EDIT:** However, it is something you can write a unit test for.

Comment: Good call... and you could apply the unit test response to all other solutions as well.. find all classes that implement an interface with reflection and check they have an expected static property/field/const/attribute. Good call! (I love unit tests!)

Answer (score 2):

You can create a static property on your base common class `foowriter`.

You can then override this property in each child class and return the data you need. The property is static so there won't be a need to instantiate.

```
public class foowriter
{
    public static string Extension
    {
        get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
    }

}

public class foobar
{
    public static string Extension
    {
        get { return "bar"; }
    }

}

public class fooboo
{
    public static string Extension
    {
        get { return "boo"; }
    }

}
```

Comment: Can't have static virtual. (e.g. `abstract class a { public static virtual string tau; }`
`class b : a {
  public static override string tau = "bbb"; }` doesn't compile)

Comment: Sorry, right. No need for virtual for static members.

Comment: The NotImplementedException is a nice touch!

Comment: Problem is that you still wouldn't pick it up 'til run time, as opposed to compile time, if a concrete foowriter didn't implement its own Extension method.

Comment: Yes, you wouldn't. But so you wouldn't with reflection. Static members cannot be marked abstract and you cannot use static methods to implement an interface.

Comment: Exactly. Rock and a hard place. Essentially I want exactly that, but I can't, so I need a better alternative, without compromising on compile time checking.

Answer (score 0):

**Use reflection to look up static property**

Use reflection to get all concrete classes:

```
var type = typeof(foowriter);
var types = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
    .SelectMany(s => s.GetTypes())
    .Where(t => type.IsAssignableFrom(t) && !t.IsAbstract && !t.IsInterface);
```

Then use reflection to get all the field values of your name:

```
var outputFormats = new List<string>();
foreach (var t in types)
{
var prop = t.GetFields().First(i => i.Name == "outputFormat");
    outputFormats.Add(prop.GetValue(null));
}
```

Bad thing about this is that it doesn't allow for compile time checking .'. no enforcement that a derived class has too have the outputFormat field :-/